# Unable to call a hook from template file in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to call my custom hook from a template file. I have inserted the hook in ps_hook table. I have created a module and linked it to the hook. Also I have grafted the module to the hook using Modules -> Postions -> Transplant a module.

This is mymodule.php file.

```
  <?php
 if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
exit;

class MyModule extends Module
{
public function __construct()
{
$this->name = 'mymodule';
$this->tab = 'front_office_features';
$this->version = 1.0;
$this->author = 'Sarfaraz Raj';
$this->need_instance = 0;

parent::__construct();

$this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
$this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

}

public function install()
{
if (parent::install() == false OR !$this->registerHook('displayDateSlot'))
return false;
return true;
}
public function hookDisplayDateSlot( $params )
{
 //global $smarty;
$this->context->smarty->assign(
    array(
       // 'my_module_name' => Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'),
       // 'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display'),
        'my_module_message' => $this->l('This is a simple text message'), 
        'HOOK_DISPLAY_DATESLOT' =>  Hook::exec('displayDateSlot')
    )
);

  return $this->display(__FILE__,'mymodule.tpl');
}


public function hookRightColumn($params)
{
 return $this->hookDisplayDateSlot($params);
}
 }
 ?>
```

I just want to know exactly where should I declare 'HOOK_DISPLAY_DATESLOT' =>  Hook::exec('displayDateSlot') line. Name of my hook is displayDateSlot.

Comment: Please reply soon as I need to resolve this problem asap.

Answer (score 0):

NO need to write again 
'HOOK_DISPLAY_DATESLOT' =>  Hook::exec('displayDateSlot')

your hook is establish and you can install it through admin side and see the appearance in front side.